# Is it possible to use import without naming a variable?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to adhere to the standardJS syntax, so I don't want to define variables that I don't use. Is this possible to do using the import syntax without setting a variable?

```
require('flickity-imagesloaded')
```

Comment: Yes. [15 chars]

Comment: Is StandardJS giving you a warning or error?

Comment: severity: 'Error'
message: ''imagesloaded' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)'
at: '7,8'

Comment: Just like how you have it in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can. Looking at the documentation of [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you can do:

```
import "flickity-imagesloaded";
```

This will import the entire module, but wouldn't bind any variable.

(And like it was said in @Scimonster's answer, and just as you mentioned in your question, if you're in Node, you can use `require` instead of import)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like you have in your question:

```
require('flickity-imagesloaded')
```

There's nothing magical about the `var someModule = require('something')` script. You assign a variable to the result of a function call. If you're not ever going to need that variable, just call the function.

This is common when doing something with side-effects, such as polyfilling missing features in older versions.

Comment: I was intrested in using import xxx from 'flickity-imagesloaded' but without xxx from